# ¿como especificar las coordenadas en el align(alinear) en delphi?

Tags: delphi

Comos ustedes saben en delphi hay una opcion llamada align(alinear) que reajusta los objetos pero de una forma predeterminada osea por ejemplo, dentro del align  hay un opcion que dice ''center''(osea alinear al centro) si lo pongo me pone el o los objetos en el centro pero lo que pasa es que si pongo varios objetos en la opción center lo que hace es que me pone los objetos uno arriba de otro.Lo que quiero hacer es ponerlo que yo elija en que lugar se moveran los objetos que vaya a mover.Les dejare algunas imagenes para que vean lo que trato de decir.introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres lograr? quizás debieras añadir una imagen con el resultado que deseas.

Comment: yo iba a poner varias imágenes pero me decía que no puedo poner mas de una imagen a las vez pero en fin lo que quiero lograr es que uno o varios objetos cuando vaya a maximizar el formulario se reajuste  o mas bien se reorganicen debidamente porque normalmente cuando maximizas un formulario los objetos se quedan igual y no se reajustan ni se organizan. Quiero que se reajusten y se organicen cuando maximize un formulario.

Comment: No existe tal cosa como "reajustarse debidamente", por eso mi pregunta. Si el sitio no te deja poner más de una imagen, quita la del IDE y pon la imagen de lo que quieres conseguir, creo que eso mejorará mucho y hará que tu pregunta pueda responderse.

Comment: Ese cuadro negro es el cuadro de diseño de delphi  ya que no podía mandarte mas de una imagen lo que hice fue tomar como referencia el cuadro de diseño.Cuando cree el objeto que vez ahí llamado ''Ejemplo'' lo puse en el centro y cuando lo ejecuto esta exactamente igual como lo ves en el cuadro negro pero como vez en el cuadro azul que es el formulario ejecutado si altero el tamaño del formulario el objeto llamado ''Ejemplo'' no se altera al igual que el formulario sin importar de que tamaño ponga el formulario si maximizas el formulario el objeto ejemplo no se altera.

Comment: Lo que quiero hacer es que ese objeto se vaya ajustando al tamaño del formulario y que yo pueda en un caso de que tenga mas objetos los pueda ordenar para cuando el formulario tenga que agrandarse o maximizarse no se desorganicen los objetos y queden como cuando los ejecutas en tamaño normal.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas, me parece que lo que estás buscando es el FlowPanel aunque no estoy seguro si está disponible en XE8.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En tiempo de ejecución, si cambias el tamaño de tu formulario, los controles se acomodarán automáticamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].